# How to automatically inserting default key in prais winsten estimation?

Tags: r, statistics

I got an error message saying
Error in prais_winsten(agvprc.lm1, data = data) :
argument "index" is missing, with no default

How can I avoid inputting all the features

agvprc.lm1=lm(log(avgprc) ~ mon+tues+wed+thurs+t+wave2+wave3)
summary(agvprc.lm1)

agvprc.lm.pw = prais_winsten(agvprc.lm1, data=data)
summary(agvprc.lm.pw)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've understood the question correctly, but to avoid the "Error in prais_winsten(agvprc.lm1, data = data) : argument "index" is missing, with no default" error you need to provide an 'index' to the function (which is a character variable of "ID" and "time"). Using the inbuilt mtcars dataset as an example, with "cyl" as "time":

```r
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("prais")
library(prais)
#> Loading required package: sandwich
#> Loading required package: pcse
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pcse'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:sandwich':
#> 
#>     vcovPC

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, group = cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = hp), width = 0.2)
```

[image]

```r
agvprc.lm1 <- lm(log(mpg) ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars)
summary(agvprc.lm1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = log(mpg) ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.35699 -0.09882  0.01111  0.11948  0.24118 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  3.7829495  0.1062183  35.615  < 2e-16 ***
#> cyl         -0.1072513  0.0279213  -3.841 0.000615 ***
#> hp          -0.0011031  0.0007273  -1.517 0.140147    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.1538 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7503, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7331 
#> F-statistic: 43.57 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.83e-09

agvprc.lm.pw <- prais_winsten(formula = agvprc.lm1,
                              data = mtcars,
                              index = c("hp", "cyl"))
#> Iteration 0: rho = 0
#> Iteration 1: rho = 0.6985
#> Iteration 2: rho = 0.7309
#> Iteration 3: rho = 0.7285
#> Iteration 4: rho = 0.7287
#> Iteration 5: rho = 0.7287
#> Iteration 6: rho = 0.7287
#> Iteration 7: rho = 0.7287
summary(agvprc.lm.pw)
#> 
#> Call:
#> prais_winsten(formula = agvprc.lm1, data = mtcars, index = c("hp", 
#>     "cyl"))
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.33844 -0.08166  0.03109  0.13612  0.25811 
#> 
#> AR(1) coefficient rho after 7 iterations: 0.7287
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  3.7643405  0.1116876  33.704   <2e-16 ***
#> cyl         -0.1061198  0.0298161  -3.559   0.0013 ** 
#> hp          -0.0011470  0.0007706  -1.489   0.1474    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.1077 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.973,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9712 
#> F-statistic: 523.3 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
#> 
#> Durbin-Watson statistic (original): 0.1278 
#> Durbin-Watson statistic (transformed): 0.4019
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

```
# To present the index without having to write out all of the variables
# perhaps you could use:

agvprc.lm.pw <- prais_winsten(formula = agvprc.lm1,
                              data = mtcars,
                              index = names(agvprc.lm1$coefficients)[3:2])
summary(agvprc.lm.pw)
#> 
#> Call:
#> prais_winsten(formula = agvprc.lm1, data = mtcars, index = names(agvprc.lm1$coefficients)[3:2])
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.33844 -0.08166  0.03109  0.13612  0.25811 
#> 
#> AR(1) coefficient rho after 7 iterations: 0.7287
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  3.7643405  0.1116876  33.704   <2e-16 ***
#> cyl         -0.1061198  0.0298161  -3.559   0.0013 ** 
#> hp          -0.0011470  0.0007706  -1.489   0.1474    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.1077 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.973,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9712 
#> F-statistic: 523.3 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
#> 
#> Durbin-Watson statistic (original): 0.1278 
#> Durbin-Watson statistic (transformed): 0.4019
```

NB. there are a number of assumptions here that may not apply to your actual data; with more information, such as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you will likely get a better/more informed answer on stackoverflow